# plotting a bar graph from a csv keeps giving an error

Tags: python

I need to plot a bar graph using matplotlib, I now have this as code:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

D= pandas.read_csv(sys.stdin,sep=" " , header=None, index_col=0)
D.plot(kind="bar", rot=30, legend=False)
plt.title("My plot")
plt.show()
exit(0)
```

I have a csv file:

```
1731 Friday
828 Monday
1040 Saturday
22 Sunday
1108 Thursday
901 Tuesday
1055 Wednesday
```

and the error is:
[image: Error]

Comment: Why are you passing `sys.stdin` as the file? Didn't you say you have a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to plot a histogram ? If it's the case you can run :

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.histplot(data=D, x=(to specify), y = (to specify)) 
#you can specify the column you to plot
```

Comment: I don't have access to the module seaborn.

Comment: just type in your terminal pip install seaborn

Comment: then add seaborn as above.

Comment: I can't I am on a ssh from school

Comment: What if OP doesn't want to (or can't) install extra libraries? It is better to stick with solving the problem presented in the question and maybe suggesting alternative ways as an addendum

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that x where the numbers and y the days, that was the reason it could not plotit, so all I needed to do was switch the columns and plot it.